# Не получается запустить Python скрипт из под Net Core

Tags: python, .net, asp.net-core, ironpython

Есть проект на Net Core 6
Появилась необходимость запускать скрипт питона из под Net

Для питона было установлено miniconda, для соединения с кликхаусом установлен пакет clickhouse_connect. Далее установлен IronPython и IronPython STD

Проверяю выполнение скрипта вставки через Net

```
import clickhouse_connect

client = clickhouse_connect.get_client(host='127.0.0.1', port='8123', username='default', password='',database='default')

row = [101, 'TestPythonInsert', 1000000,'']
data = [row]
client.insert('asd', 
data, 
column_names=['id', 'title', 'parent_id','external_id'],
column_type_names=['UInt64','String','Nullable(UInt64)','String'])
```

В коде написан сервис с методом запуска

```
public void RunScript(string script)
{ 
    var _engine = Python.CreateEngine();      

    var paths = new List<string>();            

    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\Lib");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\DLLs");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4");
    paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files\IronPython 3.4\Lib\site-packages");       
    
    _engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

    using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(script));
    if (stream == null)
        throw new Exception("Error creating ScriptInstance - resource stream is null");
    using var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    var _script = sr.ReadToEnd();

    var source = _engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(_script, SourceCodeKind.File);
    var compiled = source.Compile();

    var scope = _engine.CreateScope();

    try
    {
        compiled.Execute(scope);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

В каталог site-packages - добавил пакеты clickhouse_connect и все те которые были установлены из под pip
При выполнении падает на методе Execute с ошибкой "Cannot import name SafeUUID"
Что делать уже не знаю, пробовал указывать разные пути и на в текущее окружение миниконды и библиотеки, но появляются ошибки импорта с другими названиями, что делать хз.
Может кто сталкивался, что делаю не так ?

Comment: Не нужно пересказывать ошибку своими словами. **Полный стек-трейс ошибки** должен быть прямо в вопросе. А так я вообще не очень понимаю как вы `miniconda` с `IronPython` смешиваете. Мне казалось это разные экосистемы, но я могу ошибаться.